# How to only rerender a new element in an array - React

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, state

I have a web app that uses a websocket to receive information from an API I have put together.

Everything works great, however, every time new information arrives from the websocket, the whole list on my frontend (React) is updated.

Here is the relevent code:

```
    componentDidMount(prevState) {
        socketIO.on('newNotification', (response) => {
            const notifications = this.state.notifications;
            console.log(response)
            const newNotifications = response.data

            this.setState(prevState => ({
                notifications: [...this.state.notifications, newNotifications]
            }))

        });
    }
```

notifications is a list of notifications that is received from my API, which I set to the state.notifications whenever a response is received.

My understanding is React only updates what it needs to, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Here is my Notification component:

```
import React from "react"

class Notification extends React.Component {


    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
              <li 
                key = {this.props.notification.id}
                onClick={() => this.props.deleteNotificationProps(this.props.notification.id)}>
                <div className='separator-container'>
                    <div className={'notification-border ' + this.props.notification.stat_abr}>
                        <div className='notification' >
                        <div className='left-notification'>
                            <div className = 'stat-abr'>{this.props.notification.stat_abr}</div>
                            <div className = 'game-time'>{this.props.notification.game_time_string}</div>  
                        </div>
                        <div className='middle-notification'>
                        <div className='player-image'>
                            <img src={"http://nhl.bamcontent.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/" + this.props.notification.player_id.toString() + ".jpg"} alt="" className="player-img" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className = 'right-notification'> {this.props.notification.description} </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default Notification
```

I tried various diferent methods of updating the state, but nothing seems to work.

EDIT: here is the NotificationList class where the Notification component is created:

```
class NotificationList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
            {this.props.notifications.map(notification => (
              <Notification 
                id = {notification.id}
                notification = {notification}
                handleChangeProps = {this.props.handleChangeProps}
                deleteNotificationProps = {this.props.deleteNotificationProps}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the code where you iterate over the notifications to create `Notification` components.

I assume you have a `notifications.map(...)` somewhere... To only re-render new components, use the `key={...}` attribute inside of the map, with a value unique to each attribute (use index if you don't have a unique key).

e.g.

```js
<div>
    { notifications.map((notification) => <Notification
        key={notification.id}
        notification={notification}
        />)
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick Grealy. I have included the map function in my original post. I have changed this to be "key" instead of "id", however my whole array is being rerendered still.

Maybe I am misinterpretting, but I have a CSS class that is only applied for the first 10 seconds after a notification is created. When a new notification arrives, the whole list is reloaded and the CSS is applied to the whole list

Comment: Absolutely my pleasure!

Comment: Just recommenting, I didn't mean to click enter so soon on my previous comment

Comment: Check your JSX hierarchy. If a parent component is re-rendered, so too, will all it's children. You can also try wrapping your JSX element in a `React.useMemo`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong:

I had a `<ul></ul>` tag surrounding my `<li></li>` tag in my Notification class.

Removed this and all is working as it should.